# Different behaviour activity lifecycle on Sony Tablet S

Tags: android, android-activity, sony

I am a new developer on Android. I have an application working on several Android devices but I have found a weird behaviour on the activities lifecycle on an Sony Tablet S with 4.0.3 android version.
My app have an A activity wich launch a B activity, the problem is that when B is launched A is paused and destroyed, while in the other devices is paused an resumed. When I came back from B activity through back button, A has to be created again.

Any idea? I have search a lot about this issue but I have not found any similar problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should always consider that an activity that the user left will be destroyed. So what is your problem with that?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to create and display ActivityB?

Comment: Hi @WarrenFaith, my main problem is the activity A take a lot of time to create due to has to download some files from Internet each time it is created.

Comment: Well than you should consider caching the files. I how else do you handle orientation changes?

Comment: @WarrenFaith No as image picking would thus not work....

Comment: @Eduardo Did you every get this working?

Comment: @zezba9000 I dont get you

Comment: @WarrenFaith If the main Activity gets destroyed instead of paused, then you can't handle the Image Picking Intent.

Comment: I would doubt that but where do you read something about pick intent? Anyway if you use startActivityForResult(), I would expect and so far have experienced that even when an activity is destroyed, it will be created again to handle the result. Beside that, how do you expect the back button to work? It does load even destroyed activities...

Answer (score 1):

Whether an Activity gets destroyed or not is determined by the Android OS and depends not only on your device but also on the current memory usage. It isn't that unlikely that your Activities get destroyed faster on a device with a smaller memory unit or if there are other apps eating up memory (perhaps apps that won't get destroyed because they are part of the modified OS from Sony). That could happen especially if your activity A is heavy weighted with Bitmaps...

Answer (score 0):

The code I used to create and display the Activity B is the following:

```
  legendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(final View v) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LegendActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.LEGEND, _legenditems);
        startActivity(intent);
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am observing same issue with Sony Xperia Z. My calling activity(A) calls native camera with an intent (using startActivityForResult(..)).
What I am observing is A gets destroyed and when done with camera onActivtyResult(..) of A is called.

I am still trying to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: Were you every able to?

Comment: It's been a while - as far as I remember,  I used a flag to get around this issue.